# Azure DevOps use dotnet core download failed: certificate error

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in Azure Pipelines that is failing.  It states that it could not download the file because the certificate is expired.

Currently, specifying version `3.x` is resolving to version 3.1.201.
If I explicitly specify the previous version `3.1.103` the step succeeds with no error.

1. What 'certificate' is expired?
2. Is there a work-around? or does this just need to be reported to MSFT?

YAML

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .Net Core sdk 3.x'
  inputs:
    version: 3.x
```

Build Error

```
Tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 3.x.
Found version 3.1.201 in channel 3.1 for user specified version spec: 3.x
Version 3.1.201 was not found in cache.
Getting URL to download .NET Core sdk version: 3.1.201.
Detecting OS platform to find correct download package for the OS.
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& 'd:\a\_tasks\UseDotNet_b0ce7256-7898-45d3-9cb5-176b752bfea6\2.165.2\externals\get-os-platform.ps1'"
Primary:win-x64
Detected platform (Primary): win-x64
Downloading: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/adeab8b1-1c44-41b2-b12a-156442f307e9/65ebf805366410c63edeb06e53959383/dotnet-sdk-3.1.201-win-x64.zip
##[error]Failed while installing version: 3.1.201 at path: C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/dotnet with error: Could not download installation package from this URL: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/adeab8b1-1c44-41b2-b12a-156442f307e9/65ebf805366410c63edeb06e53959383/dotnet-sdk-3.1.201-win-x64.zip Error: Error: certificate has expired
Finishing: Use .Net Core sdk 3.x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure DevOps use dotnet core download failed: certificate error

AFAIK, this does not involve any client certificate when we are using this `UseDotNet@2` task.

So, the certificate should more related to the SDK itself, it should be renewed across the board by the SDK provider.

Besides, other members have reacted to the same issue recently, and this issue no longer exists.

[Expired certificate on Dotnet install](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/979557/expired-certificate-on-dotnet-install-httpsdotnetc.html)

Try to check if you still have this issue. Also, you could try to explicitly specify the previous version `3.1.201` in that task.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful for additional background information. I was able to switch back to specifying `3.x` after the issue was resolved by the SDK provider.